# Any way to determine if an element is wrapped?

Tags: javascript, html, word-wrap

Basically, I have a certain HTML element (in this case, a div) that is wrapping to a new line in the case of a below average screen resolution, due to a floating element. I want to control this behavior, placing and/or styling the element differently if indeed it is currently wrapped or will be wrapped upon resize/onload.

Is this possible?

Comment: What if a user wants to enhance the size by C^+ or something of that nature.  Do you still want to resize given element to be specific width?  That would frustrate me if you kept resizing what I was trying to enhance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can count the number of text rectangles it has using [`element.getClientRects()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.getClientRects), which returns a ClientRect object for each border-box of an element.  This must be done on an inline element such as a `<span>` for each line of text to have its own border-box, but it's simple enough to use:

```
window.onresize = function () {
    var span = document.getElementById("myDiv").getElementsByTagName("span")[0],
        rect = span.getClientRects();

    if (rect.length > 1) // more than 1 line of text
        doSomethingWithElement(span.parentNode);
}
```

Comment: I like the direction you're headed here--but let's say the element contains more than simple text...what then?

Comment: @ChrisCashwell Calculate width of each element, whilst looping, accumulate element widths, and when accumulated width exceeds the container width, you know that element has wrapped.

Comment: @ChrisCashwell: Also if it contains no simple text, you could do `???.lastElementChild.offsetTop > 0`.