# Is there a CSS way to know if an element has wrapped to a new line?

Tags: css

If I have a number of inline-block elements on a line, I want to be able to style the elements that have wrapped to the next line differently.

e.g.

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div style='display: inline-block; width: 500px'>...</div>
    <div style='display: inline-block; width: 500px'>...</div>
</div>
```

So, when the browser width < 1000, the second child `<div>` can have different styling.

I know I can do it in js, but I am trying to avoid it. I also know I can use media queries, but I am concerned that the min-width cutoff may not be exactly the same as when the `<div>`'s wrap (I do not know their exact sizes).

Comment: This is a great question. I have a need, but mine is regarding `display:flex` and using `flex-wrap: wrap`. It would be great know if the items have been wrapped to change styles... this way things can stay responsive with relatively less code..

Comment: You can do it [with javascript by checking the number of rectangles the element creates with `getClientRects().length > 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4863438/1366033)

Answer (score 7):

CSS only provides a `::first-line` pseudo-element for identifying the first line in a run of line boxes. It does not provide any pseudo-elements for any other lines, nor does it provide any pseudo-classes for matching inline-level elements based on the line they are on.

You can use `::first-line` to style the first line of elements differently (i.e. instead of styling the second line of elements, apply those styles to all lines and style the first line as originally intended), but this only works for a limited set of properties.

Comment: Yup, unfortunately this looks like it's limited to style formatting. You can't do interesting things with eg dimensions or visibility. The properties that it supports are here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line