# detect 2 rows in navigator and force toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

He all guys, im have some issues I cannot fix. First of all I need to commentar that all my content is dynamic so, its why i'm not doing fix `width`. I have a main horizontal navigator with some "categories"

but these re totally dynamic. The problem is, i would like to make a toggle menu (when this navigator overflow/collapse).

**Example:**
https://jsfiddle.net/d81bgzkx/

So, depend the window width many times it goes 2 rows... and its then when I want it to force the toggle menu.

Is it possible?

If it is, thank you guys!

Comment: No...CSS cannot detect overflow.

Comment: You'll have to use media queries or JavaScript.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944347/is-there-a-css-way-to-know-if-an-element-has-wrapped-to-a-new-line

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887372/detect-browser-wrapped-lines-via-javascript