# How to hide text if prior text wraps onto new line in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jinja2

Using Jinja2 templating engine

```
<div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
    <small class="me-2 d-flex gap-2 description-container">
        <span id="description-text" class="description-text">
            {% if photo.description %}
            {{ photo.description }}
            {% endif %}
        </span>
        <span id="dimension-text" class="dimension-text text-muted">
            {% if photo.width and photo.height %}
            (Dimensions: {{ photo.width }} x {{ photo.height }})
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </small>
    <small class="float-end text-muted text-end">
        {% if photo.category %}
        {{ photo.category }}
        {% endif %}
    </small>
</div>
```

When the description-text is too long, it makes a new line in the footer and wraps the text to the new line since it can't fit itself with dimension-text. Because of this, the dimension-text also wraps to the new line to use up the extra space which looks kind of ugly.

Is there a way to find out when there is no more space to fit both the description & dimension texts, and if so, get rid of the dimension-text span? Once there is enough space to fit both on the same line, let the dimension-text re-appear.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thinking, I realized the best way of doing this was to just check the width of the footer element and compare it to the total width of its child elements to see if the child elements required more space than what's available.

Here is my solution:

```
<script>
const whiteSpace = 50;
const descriptionTexts = document.getElementsByClassName('description-text');
const dimensionTexts = document.getElementsByClassName('dimension-text');
const categoryTexts = document.getElementsByClassName('category-text');

function toggleDimensionText() {
    for (let i = 0; i < descriptionTexts.length; i++) {
        const descriptionText = descriptionTexts[i];
        const dimensionText = dimensionTexts[i];
        const categoryText = categoryTexts[i];
        const footer = descriptionText.parentElement.parentElement;
        const footerWidth = footer.offsetWidth;
        let dimensionTextWidth = dimensionText.offsetWidth;
        const descriptionTextWidth = descriptionText.offsetWidth;
        const categoryTextWidth = categoryText.offsetWidth;

        if (window.getComputedStyle(dimensionText).display == 'block') {
            if (!enoughSpace(footerWidth, descriptionTextWidth, dimensionTextWidth, categoryTextWidth)) {
                dimensionText.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
        if (window.getComputedStyle(dimensionText).display == 'none') {
            dimensionText.style.display = 'block';
            dimensionTextWidth = dimensionText.offsetWidth;
            if (enoughSpace(footerWidth, descriptionTextWidth, dimensionTextWidth, categoryTextWidth)) break;
            else dimensionText.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
}

function enoughSpace(footerWidth, descriptionTextWidth, dimensionTextWidth, categoryTextWidth) {
    return footerWidth >= descriptionTextWidth + dimensionTextWidth + categoryTextWidth + whiteSpace;
}

// Call the toggleDimensionText function initially and whenever the window is resized
toggleDimensionText();
window.addEventListener('resize', toggleDimensionText);
```

This solution uses [offSetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth). The `whitespace` variable is used to account for the space taken up by things like margins and other "whitespace" in the footer.

I set the display of the `dimensionText` back to `block` and calculated its offset width again because when it's display is `none`, there is no width. Since I set it back to `none` if there isn't enough space in the same "frame", there is no flickering in the browser.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In elements with plain text, each line of text as it is displayed in the browser gets its own [`DOMRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMRect). Because your `.description-text` box is just plain text, you can get the element's `DOMRect`s with [`.getClientRects()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects) and if its `.length` is greater than 1 (the element has more than one `DOMRect`), then the text is wrapped. This is very similar to [this answer from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4863438/13376511) (the method still works twelve years later).

You can then use this to the hide `.dimension-text` boxes in each footer by looping over all the footers and checking if their `.description-text` is wrapped. If it is, then change the `.dimension-text`'s `display` CSS style to `none`, otherwise you can set it to `inline` (the default for `<span>` elements). You'll have to do this process when the DOM first loads and every time the window resizes because text might become wrapped or unwrapped.

```js
function textIsWrapped(el) {
  return el.getClientRects().length > 1;
}

function hideLongDimensionSizes() {
  const footers = document.getElementsByClassName('card-footer');
  for (const footer of footers) {
    const desc = footer.querySelector('.description-text');
    const dims = footer.querySelector('.dimension-text');
    dims.style.display = textIsWrapped(desc) ? 'none' : 'inline';
  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', hideLongDimensionSizes);
hideLongDimensionSizes();
```

```css
/* example styles */
.card-footer {
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
  <small class="me-2 d-flex gap-2 description-container">
        <span id="description-text" class="description-text">
            A photo
        </span>
        <span id="dimension-text" class="dimension-text text-muted">
            (Dimensions: 100 x 200)
        </span>
    </small>
  <small class="float-end text-muted text-end">
        Example
    </small>
</div>

<div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
  <small class="me-2 d-flex gap-2 description-container">
        <span id="description-text" class="description-text">
            A photo with a really long description that takes up two lines.
        </span>
        <span id="dimension-text" class="dimension-text text-muted">
            (Dimensions: 100 x 200)
        </span>
    </small>
  <small class="float-end text-muted text-end">
        Example
    </small>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything..., I am console logging the .getClientRects().length and it always logs **1** even when visibly wrapping

Comment: @MyPing0 Can you provide a screenshot? Also, what browser are you using? I tested this on Chrome 115.0.5790.170

Comment: Yes I am using the latest version of Chrome, I have updated my original post to include the screenshot of two examples, please have a look.